# Couldn't view data to TableView JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I am beginner of javafx.i ran in to the problem with while loading the table.i want to retrieve the records from database to java fx tableview but couldn't view the records i don't why.what i tried so far i attached below.please fix the problem what ever in the code snippet.

```
  @FXML
private TableView<Student> table;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Student, String> IDColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Student, String> NameColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Student, String>  MobileColumn;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Student, String> CourseColumn;
  public void table()
    {
        ObservableList<Student> students = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
         try 
         {
             pst = con.prepareStatement("select id,name,mobile,course from registation");
             ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
             
         {
            while (rs.next())
            {
                Student stud = new Student();
                stud.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                stud.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                stud.setMobile(rs.getString("mobile"));
                stud.setCourse(rs.getString("course"));
             }
        }
                
                IDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("id"));
                NameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("name"));
                MobileColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("mobile"));
                CourseColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("course"));

         } 
         catch (SQLException ex)
         {
             Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
    }
```

**Student**

i have created the class student

```
public class Student {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String mobile;
    private String course;

    public Student() 
    {
        
    }

    public Student(int id, String name, String mobile, String course) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.course = course;
    }
    
 
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
```

Comment: how to add into the list

Comment: work through a tutorial on how to use java language basics, particularly on how to use collections

Comment: [Simple JavaFX collections tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0220__JavaFX_Collections.htm) and a [more complex Java collections tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/TOC.html).